# Why is my React app returning an #152 error when using fetch?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm learning React trying to build a simple app that for now should just render the result of a fetch from an API that I created inside django. Instead, I am getting the #152 error and I have no clue what am I doing wrong. Looking up, it seems that this error occurs when there's a comment at the beginning of the return statement, but there's no comment on mine. Here's my code:

```
function App() {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        question_number: 1,
        is_any_option_selected: false,
        selected_option: 0
    });

    console.log(`at state, the question number is ${state.question_number}`);

    fetch(`/question/${state.question_number}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(question => {
            console.log(`inside fetch, the question text is ${question.text}`);
            const question_text = question.text;
            return (
                <Question question_text={question_text} />
            )
        })
}


function Question(props) {
    console.log(`inside Question, the question text is: ${props.question_text}`);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>text: {props.question_text}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

both the console.log after the state declaration and after the second .then work, just the one inside Question that prints nothing on the console

Thanks in advance and sorry for the not-so-great english :)

Comment: what response state is?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning nothing when your component is rendered.
Moreover if you call fetch inside the component it will be called on each render for this you need to call it inside `useEffect`:

Try this way:

```
function App() {
    const [text, setText] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`/question/${state.question_number}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(question => {
            setText(question.text);
        });
    }, []);

    return <Question question_text={text} />
}
```